# Delete all target links and files before running GNU Stow

Tags: bash, shell-script

GNU Stow does not run properly if the target files already exist. So, i have written a script which will first delete all files and links in the target then run Stow.

```
#!/bin/bash

fd --hidden --ignore-file .gitignore --base-directory="$HOME/.dotfiles/.common-dotfiles" --type l --type f | sd ^. $HOME | xargs -I{} rm {}
stow --no-folding --target="$HOME" --dir="$HOME/.dotfiles" --restow .common-dotfiles
```

But my gut is telling me that this is not a good idea. What am I missing here? Is there any risk running this script? How can I improve this script?

**Update 1:**

GNU Stow create an exact copy of the source directory structure in the target. So, I first take the directory structure of the source. Change the path to match the target. Then run `xargs -I{} rm {}` on it.

I have broken the output of the pipe bellow.

First I am searching all the files in the `$HOME/.dotfiles/.common-dotfiles` directory.

```
% fd --hidden --ignore-file .gitignore --base-directory="$HOME/.dotfiles/.common-dotfiles" --type l --type f
.config/VSCodium/User/globalStorage/alefragnani.project-manager/projects.json
.config/VSCodium/User/globalStorage/state.vscdb
.config/VSCodium/User/keybindings.json
.config/VSCodium/User/settings.json
.config/VSCodium/User/snippets/c.json
.config/VSCodium/User/snippets/custom-snippets.code-snippets
.config/VSCodium/product.json
```

Now I am modifying the path using piping the output of previous command to `sd ^. $HOME` to match the target directory.

```
% fd --hidden --ignore-file .gitignore --base-directory="$HOME/.dotfiles/.common-dotfiles" --type l --type f | sd ^. $HOME
/home/ismail/.config/VSCodium/User/globalStorage/alefragnani.project-manager/projects.json
/home/ismail/.config/VSCodium/User/globalStorage/state.vscdb
/home/ismail/.config/VSCodium/User/keybindings.json
/home/ismail/.config/VSCodium/User/settings.json
/home/ismail/.config/VSCodium/User/snippets/c.json
/home/ismail/.config/VSCodium/User/snippets/custom-snippets.code-snippets
/home/ismail/.config/VSCodium/product.json
```

So, now I am no longer deleting files in `$HOME/.dotfiles/.common-dotfiles` but in `$HOME`.

Comment: In by experience stow creates and removes links. I never had a problem.

Comment: This will break if any of your file names contain newlines. Probably not an issue for dotfiles, but might be worth thinking about.

Comment: @terdon how can I fix the new line issue?

Comment: Probably by using `find -type f -o type l -delete` instead of `fd`, but please [edit] your question and explain exactly what files should be removed and what files kept. I _think_ you want to delete every file or symlink under `$HOME/.dotfiles/.common-dotfiles` except `$HOME/.dotfiles/.common-dotfiles/.gitignore`, is that correct?

Comment: @terdon I have updated the question to explain what I am doing.

Comment: I don't want to post an answer because I don't know the first thing about `stow`, but this `find` command should remove the files you want to remove: `find . -maxdepth 1 \( -type f -o -type l \) -print0 | sed -z "s|^.|$HOME|" | xargs -0 -I{} rm {}`. ***test it before using!*** You can replace `rm` with `echo` to get the list of files that will be removed. Oh, and this assumes GNU tools pretty much in all steps.

Comment: Your question is vague. I've used `Stow` recently for the first time, and In *my case* it worked well: get the latest version of `mtr` on my system. It never occurred to me to try to run my `Stow` *installation* alongside the older ver of `mtr` until I read your question. I used `apt purge mtr` before I started with `Stow`. If you don't do this, I don't know if it will work, but then I don't know exactly what you mean by `target`. FWIW - I posted my [`Stow` recipe on GitHub](https://github.com/seamusdemora/PiFormulae/blob/master/InstallSoftwareWithStow.md). Thanks!

Comment: I use Ansible and shell scripting to check for conflicting target files in my $HOME folder and delete them before running GNU Stow. [I explain my approach here.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/746076/572504)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done some [research](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/680413/opposite-of-adopt-option-for-gnu-stow) and found the answer in the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/stow/manual/stow.html#Invoking-Stow).

> ‘--adopt’
>
> Warning! This behaviour is specifically intended to alter the contents of your stow directory. If you do not want that, this option
> is not for you.
>
> When stowing, if a target is encountered which already exists but is a plain file (and hence not owned by any existing stow package),
> then normally Stow will register this as a conflict and refuse to
> proceed. This option changes that behaviour so that the file is moved
> to the same relative place within the package’s installation image
> within the stow directory, and then stowing proceeds as before. So
> effectively, the file becomes adopted by the stow package, without its
> contents changing.
>
> This is particularly useful when the stow package is under the control of a version control system, because it allows files in the
> target tree, with potentially different contents to the equivalent
> versions in the stow package’s installation image, to be adopted into
> the package, then compared by running something like ‘git diff ...’
> inside the stow package, and finally either kept (e.g. via ‘git commit
> ...’) or discarded (‘git checkout HEAD ...’).

So, what I should do is:

```
git checkout HEAD
stow --adopt --stow .common-dotfiles
git checkout HEAD
stow --restow .common-dotfiles
```

If we need to keep some changes, then we can run `git diff`, and resolve the merge conflicts after `stow --adopt` command.

In the above commands i use `restore .` instead of `checkout HEAD`.